# Find the value of inverse function with $ 2 \pi $ argument

Tags: functions

If $ f(x) = (2x-3 \pi)^5 + (4/3)x + cos(x) $ and g is the inverse function of f, then what is the value of $ g'(2 \pi) $

Mt try :

[image]

Comment: Please use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your equations.

Comment: You've missed out the power on $(2y-3\pi)$ after implicitly differentiating.

Comment: Other than that, it seems fine to me :). I'm not sure you'd have a closed form for $g(2\pi)$ though.

Answer (score 2):

We have $f(\frac{3}{2} \pi) = 2\pi$, so $g(2\pi) = \frac{3}{2} \pi$. An ugly exercise (in my opinion) because one have to guess this value.

Comment: Clever - I hadn't thought of this. You could probably find the value with the Lagrange Inversion Theorem if it wasn't possible by inspection.